# Unable to download multiple files with this python script

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

This script uses beautiful soup to parse all pdf documents on a particular page of a web site.  The script successfully downloads one file but will not download all the files that are returned.  I need help making this download all pdf documents that I have parsed.

I have done research but have found no answers

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import html5lib
import lxml

#RFP_Import = ('http://www.staffordmsd.org/cms/One.aspx?    portalId=895956&pageId=1606144')
RFP_Import =     ('http://www.staffordmsd.org/departments/business_operations/bids_and_proposals')
place_hoder = ('http://www.staffordmsd.org')

def get_pdf_links():
    r = requests.get(RFP_Import)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    pdf_links = [place_hoder + link['href'] for link in links if     link['href'].endswith('pdf')]
    return pdf_links



def download_pdf_links (pdf_links):
    for link in pdf_links:
        file_name = link.split("/")[-1]
        print ("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        print ('%s downloaded!\n'%file_name)
        print ('all RFPs downloaded!')
        return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
        pdf_links = get_pdf_links()
        download_pdf_links(pdf_links)
```

Successfully downloads first pdf document and then stops.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import html5lib
import lxml

#RFP_Import = ('http://www.staffordmsd.org/cms/One.aspx?       portalId=895956&pageId=1606144')
RFP_Import =     ('http://www.staffordmsd.org/departments/business_operations/bids_and_proposals')
place_hoder = ('http://www.staffordmsd.org')

def get_pdf_links():
    r = requests.get(RFP_Import)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    pdf_links = [place_hoder + link['href'] for link in links if     link['href'].endswith('pdf')]
return pdf_links



def download_pdf_links (pdf_links):
    for link in pdf_links:
        file_name = link.split("/")[-1]
        print ("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        print ('%s downloaded!\n'%file_name)
        print ('all RFPs downloaded!')
        return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
        pdf_links = get_pdf_links()
        download_pdf_links(pdf_links)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `download_pdf_link` you are using `return` inside your loop, which will return after the first iteration of the loop and stop downloading files. You need to return after the loop finishes by putting it on the same indentation as the start of the loop like this:

```py
def download_pdf_links (pdf_links):
    for link in pdf_links:
        file_name = link.split("/")[-1]
        print ("Downloading file:%s"%file_name)
        r = requests.get(link, stream = True)
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
        print ('%s downloaded!\n'%file_name)
    # Un-indented so it happens after the loop finishes.
    print ('all RFPs downloaded!')
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside `download_pdf_links()`, `return` is misaligned. It should be aligned with `for`. Otherwise, it is part of the `for` cycle and the function terminates after the first iteration.

This is probably also true for `print ('all RFPs downloaded!')`. I guess you want that printed out at the end of the for cycle, after you have been through **all** links.

Comment: Oof. Beat me to it.